# JavaScript position issue with range input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good afternoon everyone

I am stuck on a JavaScript/CSS/HTML problem, let me take a minute to explain

1. I have written a quote system for a web site i run (http://www.liquidationmadeeasy.co.uk/quote.html)
2. I have followed an example that uses framesets in order to create different stages to the quote but without navigating to a seperate page. This worked Great.
3. On each fieldset i introduced a range input. I am going to perform a calculation and it forces the user to enter a numeric value.
4. I then followed another tutorial in order to introduce a bubble displaying the selected value of the range control.
5. When the page loads it draws the bubble at the side of each range control. However when i navigate to the second frameset the bubble for all the items is drawn in the middle of the page (not in the correct position) and all on top of each other.
6. when the user selects a vale from the range control the bubble is then redrawn in the correct position.

I would like to automatically redraw all of the bubbles on the second stage of the quote when the user navigates away from the first stage.

I would assume that this is failing because I reset the value of the range input on the change event which is only triggered when the user changes the value

Could anyone point me in the right direction

**HTML**

```
    <form id="msform" method="post" action="quoteresult.php">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active">Debts</li>
        <li>Assets</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">What You Owe</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your companys financial possition</h3>
        <label for="overdraft">Overdraft:</label>
        <input type="range" name="overdraft" id="overdraft" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500" />
        <output for="overdraft">1</output>
        <label for="vat">VAT:</label>
        <input type="range" name="vat" id="vat" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500" />
        <output for="vat">1</output>
        <label for="paye">PAYE:</label>
        <input type="range" name="paye" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500"/>
        <output for="paye">1</output>
        <label for="corporationtax">Corporation Tax:</label>
        <input type="range" name="corporationtax" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500" />
        <output for="corporationtax">1</output>
        <label for="tradecreditors">Trade Creditors:</label>
        <input type="range" name="tradecreditors" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500"  />
         <output for="tradecreditors">1</output>
         <label for="rent">Rent:</label>
        <input type="range" name="rent" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500" />
        <output for="rent">1</output>
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Asset Values</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">What are you assets worth?</h3>
        <label for="debtors">Debtors:</label>
        <input type="range" name="debtors" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500" />
        <output for="debtors">1</output>
        <label for="fixtures">Fixtures:</label>
        <input type="range" name="fixtures"  value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500"/>
        <output for="fixtures">1</output>
        <label for="stock">Stock:</label>
        <input type="range" name="stock" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500" />
        <output for="stock">1</output>
        <label for="vehicles">Vehicles:</label>
        <input type="range" name="vehicles" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500" />
        <output for="vehicles">1</output>
        <label for="cash">Cash:</label>
        <input type="range" name="cash" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500" />
        <output for="cash">1</output>
        <label for="plant">Plant/Machinery:</label>
        <input type="range" name="plant" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500"/>
        <output for="plant">1</output>
        <label for="property">Property:</label>
        <input type="range" name="property" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500" />
        <output for="property">1</output>
        <label for="other">Other:</label>
        <input type="range" name="other" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500" />
        <output for="other">1</output>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
        <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
        <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company Name" />
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
    /*form styles*/
    #msform {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
    #msform fieldset {
    background: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 20px 30px;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10%;

    /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
    position: absolute;
}
    /*Hide all except first fieldset*/
    #msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
}
    /*inputs*/
    #msform input, #msform textarea {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}
    /*buttons*/
    #msform .action-button {
    width: 100px;
    background: #27AE60;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    }
    #msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
    }
    /*headings*/
    .fs-title {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #2C3E50;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .fs-subtitle {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    /*progressbar*/
    #progressbar {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
    counter-reset: step;
    }
    #progressbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 9px;
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    }
    #progressbar li:before {
    content: counter(step);
    counter-increment: step;
    width: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #333;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    top: 9px;
    z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
    /*connector not needed before the first step*/
    content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
    background: #27AE60;
    color: white;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
            this.redraw();
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;

        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    document.getElementById("msform").submit();

    return false;
})

     $(function() {
       var el, newPoint, newPlace, offset, newTop;
       $("input[type='range']").change(function() {
         el = $(this);
         width = el.width();
         newPoint = (el.val() - el.attr("min")) / (el.attr("max") - el.attr("min"));
         offset = -1.3;
         newTop = el.position().top - 10;
         newLeft = el.position().left + width + 10;
         if (newPoint < 0) { newPlace = 0;  }
         else if (newPoint > 1) { newPlace = width; }
         else { newPlace = width * newPoint + offset; offset -= newPoint;}
         el
           .next("output")
           .css({
             left: newLeft + "px",
             top: newTop + "px"
           })
           .text(el.val());
       })
       .trigger('change');
     });
```

Comment: There's no Java there, you should edit your post before getting downvoted

Comment: i apologise, its been a long day. Thanks for editing

Comment: There are also no framesets, you obviously mean fieldset but you might want to edit and avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a proposed solution, but I have to post it as such so I can upload screenshots of my results.  I copied your HTML, CSS, and JS verbatim (though I had to wrap the HTML appropriately, of course), and I have not encountered the bug you describe.
I tried using two different jQuery CDN files:

- https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"
- https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"

Here are screenshots of the rendered 2nd phase, "Asset Values", in Firefox 29.0.1, Chrome 35, Safari 6.1.4, and IE10.  The first three on Mac OS X 10.7.5, the latter on Windows 8 VM running on VirtualBox/.  Order is Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE:

[image: Firefox 29.0.1]

[image: Chrome 35]

[image: Safari 6.1.4]

[image: IE10]

As you can see, with the exception of Firefox the rendering is broken to some degree or other in all the browsers, but the bug you describe does not appear.
I also note that the website you link to: http://www.liquidationmadeeasy.co.uk/quote.html
...appears to be working fine, too, in Firefox 29:

[image: Live site]

Do you want to post the exact browser w/ version you are using to test?

---

P.S.

Not related to your problem, but be aware that most of your HTML  elements have "for" attributes that are pointing to the "name" attribute of the  instead of an "id" attribute.  See [<label> element in MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

This is the case for the following labels:

First fieldset:

```
    <label for="paye">PAYE:</label>
    <input type="range" name="paye" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500"/>
    <output for="paye">1</output>
    <label for="corporationtax">Corporation Tax:</label>
    <input type="range" name="corporationtax" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500" />
    <output for="corporationtax">1</output>
    <label for="tradecreditors">Trade Creditors:</label>
    <input type="range" name="tradecreditors" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500"  />
    <output for="tradecreditors">1</output>
    <label for="rent">Rent:</label>
    <input type="range" name="rent" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500" />
```

Second fieldset:

```
    <label for="debtors">Debtors:</label>
    <input type="range" name="debtors" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500" />
    <output for="debtors">1</output>
    <label for="fixtures">Fixtures:</label>
    <input type="range" name="fixtures"  value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500"/>
    <output for="fixtures">1</output>
    <label for="stock">Stock:</label>
    <input type="range" name="stock" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500" />
    <output for="stock">1</output>
    <label for="vehicles">Vehicles:</label>
    <input type="range" name="vehicles" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500" />
    <output for="vehicles">1</output>
    <label for="cash">Cash:</label>
    <input type="range" name="cash" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500" />
    <output for="cash">1</output>
    <label for="plant">Plant/Machinery:</label>
    <input type="range" name="plant" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500"/>
    <output for="plant">1</output>
    <label for="property">Property:</label>
    <input type="range" name="property" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500" />
    <output for="property">1</output>
    <label for="other">Other:</label>
    <input type="range" name="other" value=0 min=0 max=1000000 step="500" />
```